# Parameterize and Execute SSIS DSTX for Data Import

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'd like to transfer a whole bunch of data between 2 SQL Server databases using SSIS.  **How can I parameterize the output of the SQL Server "Import Data" wizard and execute it to run on other environments?**

In SQL Server, I right-clicked the destination database and clicked "Import Data" and went through the wizard and chose the option to "Save SSIS Package".  This worked fine and produced a .dstx file to do the transfer between my specific databases on the server that I ran the wizard from.  Now I'd like to customize the .dstx in order to parameterize the data source and the source and destination databases to be able to run on other environments.  Then I'd like to be able to execute the .dstx package from the command line.  I'm struggling with both steps as I know almost nothing about SSIS, but I suspect that this should be an easy thing to do.

Also, trying to run "dtexec.exe" from the command line threw an error about version 3 not being able to run version 8 or some such (PackageFormatVersion is set to 8 inside the XML)?

**What is the best way to do this without needing to create an SSIS project in Visual Studio?**  I'd like to simply update the XML directly and call whatever EXE is capable of executing it and accepting parameters for the connection string, or the individual variables inside the connection string.  I'm able to successfully double-click the .dstx file and run it with the GUI, but I'd like to be able to do the same from the command line and without creating a SQL Agent job.

Here's the XML node from the .dstx file that needs to be parameterized.

```
<DTS:ConnectionManagers>
<DTS:ConnectionManager
  DTS:refId="Package.ConnectionManagers[DestinationConnectionOLEDB]"
  DTS:CreationName="OLEDB"
  DTS:DTSID="{72C15889-EC1F-4BFA-A704-7562C68B2463}"
  DTS:ObjectName="DestinationConnectionOLEDB">
  <DTS:ObjectData>
    <DTS:ConnectionManager
      DTS:ConnectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DestinationDatabase;Provider=SQLNCLI11;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=false;" />
  </DTS:ObjectData>
</DTS:ConnectionManager>
<DTS:ConnectionManager
  DTS:refId="Package.ConnectionManagers[SourceConnectionOLEDB]"
  DTS:CreationName="OLEDB"
  DTS:DTSID="{B1415B25-61D6-4202-9BC6-CA59B358B766}"
  DTS:ObjectName="SourceConnectionOLEDB">
  <DTS:ObjectData>
    <DTS:ConnectionManager
      DTS:ConnectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=SourceDatabase;Provider=SQLNCLI11;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=false;" />
  </DTS:ObjectData>
</DTS:ConnectionManager>
</DTS:ConnectionManagers>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know almost nothing about SSIS, but I suspect that this should be
>   an easy thing to do.

Sorry, it's not an easy thing to do.   The way you parameterize connections in SSIS for multiple environments is with config files and package variables, and by far the easiest way to do this is by working with a project in Visual Studio.

If you can't use Visual Studio for some reason, you could edit the xmla of the package directly in a text editor, but good luck finding a tutorial that explains how to do that, or anyone who knows how off-hand, and then good luck doing it and debugging it.   Maybe you could look at the xmla of a package that uses configurations and use it as a model, if you have one.

Comment: You can save the package and use package variables. The package variables can be set by a configuration file...

Comment: This makes me sad.  I'll just not use SSIS then and use "post deployment" scripts in my SQL Project to handle the data migrations needed.